# How Apache Kafka maintain order when it sends multiple messages to broker in parallel?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

By default, `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection == 5`, means Kafka will send up to 5 messages to broker in parallel. How can it manage the order if those message go into the same partition in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka cannot guarantee ordering of those messages if you set `retries > 0`.

If you want to have ordering guarantees you need to set this value to `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection == 1`.

The explanation is given in the Kafka doc on [producer configs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#producerconfigs) `retries`:

> Allowing retries without setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1 will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first.

Answer (score 1):

By default, with `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` > 1, batches can be reordered.

If you want to guarantee the ordering, you can:

- set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`. Depending on your throughput, this can have a significant performance impact.
- use the idempotent producer by setting `enable.idempotence` to `true`. This enables to still take advantage of `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=5` but also enforces batch ordering. When idempotence is enabled, the producer assigns sequence numbers to all batches so the  broker can validate their order. The performance impact is usually very small.